# Ranking Fetched Contacts

Tags: ios, swift, contacts

I am using the `Contacts API` for my iOS app to fetch contacts. I currently sort the fetched contacts alphabetically, but was wondering if there is *any* ability to rank and sort them by "highest interaction" (i.e. scan iMessage or phone call log to prioritize contacts)?

Any insight would be appreciated. I don't think this is possible via the `Contacts API` from what I've read, and I haven't found any existing answer commenting on this.

Answer (score 0):

iOS does not have APIs to check called numbers or other uses of contact information.  This is for obvious privacy reasons.

Ergo, your neat idea isn't possible.

Comment: hmm thanks for your answer, would CNChangeHistoryFetchRequest offer any workarounds?

Comment: @Chris What does `CNChangeHistoryFetchRequest` do?  iOS documentation doesn't say much.  Generally speaking all contact change events will of course be only about fields of [`CNContact`]https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cncontact)s.  Since `CNContact` can only hold a lost of phone numbers, I don't expect anything from `CNChangeHistoryFetchRequest`.

Comment: @Chris If you liked my answer, please ^ it and if it answers your question please checkmark it.  Thanks :-)